# Autocomplete not working with tab key in Mathematica 10.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: front-end, linux, keyboard, autocomplete

When I want to autocomplete a function I can't use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to expand what I typed in. If I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it escapes the popup suggestion menu. Autocomplete only works if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Furthermore, once the function has been expanded with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I can't use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch over the arguments of the function. Pressing it does nothing.

How can I find if it is a problem related to my own installation of Mathematica or maybe a key conflict?

I'm using Mathematica 10.3.0.0 with a Student Edition license and running
Elementary OS 0.3.1 built on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It's not a Student Edition issue, the same tab key failure happens for me using v10.3.0 and kubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I can not use my tab key anymore either and I have 10.3 and kubuntu 15.10

Comment: I can confirm the same thing happens on Linux Mint. I can add that the usual Shift+Alt+), Shift+Alt+} are not working. The only one working is Alt+]. However there are no problems in Windows 10! Could this be a general linux issue?

Comment: I tried the 10.2 and 10.3 version and it's not working on Debian stretch. I switched to 10.1 and it works fine. In the next few days I will try the 10.3.1